# c# - Change the pitch and offset in a Speech Synthesiser

Tags: c#, voice, speech-synthesis

I want to change a pitch and offset of a voice in my program, so i can get a lot of diffrent customizations (for the voice).
I already did the volume, the SpeechSynthesizer has a Volume var.

My code:

```cs
//I have a gender selection system here, but its ugly
aPrompt.ClearContent();
aPrompt.AppendText(text);
aPrompt.Culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(selected.aCulture);
sS.Volume = selected.Volume;
sS.Speak(aPrompt);
```

I have 3 slider that i want to map to the Volume, Pitch and Offset (i can make it get the value, but i dont know how to make the voice change)

Comment: It looks like you need to add some lexicons. Have you try them?     The SpeechSynthesizer can use one or more lexicons to guide its pronunciation of words.

Comment: The Speech Synthesis system does not allow for changing Pitch and Offset (?) - you can just change to a different voice. You could capture the synthesizer output and then modify it, but that is more involved.